# how to get html files using URLConnection in JAVA with login information

Tags: java, authentication, urlconnection

I want download a html page "http://www.slrclub.com/bbs/zboard.php?id=theme_gallery&category=6"

but It needs login information

My code is appended below

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.slrclub.com/bbs/zboard.php?id=theme_gallery&category=6");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.slrclub.com/");
String name = "myid";
String password = "mypass";

String authString = name + ":" + password;
System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(authString.getBytes());

connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);

InputStream is_img = connection.getInputStream();


OutputStream os_img = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( "1.html"));



for (int b; (b = is_img.read()) != -1;) {

    os_img.write(b);

}
os_img.close();

is_img.close();
```

but it did not work

how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove that authentication code and install a `java.net.Authenticator`.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is not related to 'HTTP Authorization'

www.slrclub.com didn't use HTTP Authorization.

Use your browsers web development tools to identify the mechanism that the site is using when you log in via a web browser ... and attempt to get your client to behave the same way.

Login Page : slrclub.com/login/process.php 
Method : POST 
parameter : user_id, password

Comment: In what way is 'need[ing] login information' 'not related [to] HTTP Authorization'?

Comment: Login Page : http://www.slrclub.com/login/process.php
Method : POST
parameter : user_id, password